# Duda con ejercicio listas doblemente enlazadas

Tags: c++, pilas

tengo un ejercicio de pilas, dice así:

> Implementar   el  método  de  la  clase   dll_t   void
>   select(dll_t*>& L,  const   T& x),  que guarda
>   dentro    de  la  lista   L   los punteros    a   nodos   de  la  lista   invocante   que tiene   como    contenido   x.

además, me dan las siguientes clases:

```
template <class T>
class dll_t {
private:
 dll_node_t<T>* head_;
 dll_node_t<T>* tail_;
 int sz_;
public:
  dll_t(void);
 ~dll_t(void);
  void insert_tail(dll_node_t<T>*);
  void insert_head(dll_node_t<T>*);
  dll_node_t<T>* extract_tail(void);
  dll_node_t<T>* extract_head(void);
  dll_node_t<T>* get_tail(void) const;
  dll_node_t<T>* get_head(void) const;
  bool empty(void);
  void remove(dll_node_t<T>*);
  ostream& write(ostream& os) const;
  void select(dll_t<dll_node_t<T>*>& L, const T& x);
private:
  bool igual(const T& a, const T&b);
};
```

y esta:

```
template <class T>
class dll_node_t {

private:
  dll_node_t<T>* next_;
  dll_node_t<T>* prev_;
  T data_;
public:
  dll_node_t();
  dll_node_t(const T& data);
  virtual ~dll_node_t(void);
  void set_next(dll_node_t<T>*);
  void set_prev(dll_node_t<T>*);
  dll_node_t<T>* get_next(void) const;
  dll_node_t<T>* get_prev(void) const;
  void set_data(const T& data);
  T get_data(void) const;
  ostream& write(ostream& os) const;
};
```

lo intenté hacer así, antes de compilarlo sabía que tenía algún error de base en el planteamiento:

```
template<class T>
void vector_t :: select (dll_t<dll_node_t<T>*>& L, const T& x){
dll_t<T> lista;
dll_node_t<T>* aux = lista.get_head();
while(aux!=NULL){

  T dato = aux->get_data();

  if ( dato == x){

    aux = new dll_node_t<T> (T(dato));
    L.insert_tail(aux);

  }

  aux= aux -> get_next();
}
```

No sé dónde tengo ese error en el planteamiento del ejercicio, lo sigo buscando.

Gracias

Comment: @lilezek me echas una mano con el ejercicio? Gracias

Comment: ¿Cual es el error?

Comment: he marcado como aceptadas muchas respuestas, pero en los comentarios no me aparece(no respuestas) no me aparece el tick para darla como aceptada, @SJuan76

Comment: @lilezek   antes de compilar la he liado en el planteamiento, ¿tengo algún error ahí? repito, no he compilado, pero el planteamiento lo tengo mal. Se agradece ayuda

Comment: ¿Por qué lo tienes mal?

Comment: la comparación con el dato x me suena que la tengo mal, si podrías mirar el ejercicio para ver cómo corregir planteamiento. Gracias

Comment: @lilezek        eso es lo que necesitaría una ayuda

Comment: Yo lo único que veo raro es que get_data devuelva `T` (una copia) y no `T &` (una referencia al valor original), ya que eso hace ese método de C++ ineficiente. El resto lo veo bien a simple vista, así que sino explicas mejor cuál es tu preocupación no creo que pueda ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error en el planteamiento si 
Dice

> guarda dentro de la lista L los punteros a nodos de la lista invocante

No dice  recrear los nodos nuevamente por cada nodo que se encuentre
borras esta linea         `aux = new dll_node_t<T> (T(dato));` y ya corrigues eso

Dice:

> lista invocante

Es decir `lista1->select(lista2,datox)` o `lista1.select(lista2,datox)`
Es un metodo en la clase `dll_t` En resumen si entendi bien deberia ser asi:

```
template<class T>
//Err1 NO es: void vector_t ::... es dll_t
void dll_t :: select (dll_t<dll_node_t<T>*>& L, const T& x){

//dll_t<T> lista;    
//El metodo se ejecuta en una lista pertenece a dll_t "this.get_head()"
dll_node_t<T>* aux = get_head();

while(aux!=NULL){

  T dato = aux->get_data();

  if ( dato == x){
    //Eliminar esta linea de abajo
    //aux = new dll_node_t<T> (T(dato));
    L.insert_tail(aux);    
  }    
  aux= aux -> get_next();
}    
}
```